# How to simply pull a table from mysql and then put into a java 2d array, then have a result and reverse?

Tags: java, mysql

I know a way but it should be not a good simple solution. Any very easy solution? I will do a lot of calculation then push back a 2d array result into a mysql tablea as well.

Comment: Explain bit more , your question is bit vague !

Answer (score 0):

I'd wonder why you'd do this.  It seems easier to let the relational database do all that work.  I'd write ORDER BY X DESC and get it in reversed order without having to do a lick of work on the middle tier.

Can you refrain from bringing all that data to the middle tier and perform all those operations on the database using a stored procedure?  Could be far more efficient.

But if you must, break it up into pieces:

1. Do a SELECT from the database to get a ResultSet.
2. Map the ResultSet into a 2D array (why not a Map or List or collection of some object?)
3. Get your "result" - what's that?
4. Pass the result to the database and do an INSERT or UPDATE as appropriate.

Comment: I will do massy calculation with the 2d arrays, it would be much faster to do calculation with arrays then using data in mysql to do so.